# How to put custom listview row that has specific text on the top row in listview in android

Tags: android

I have a custom list view that is getting data from server and changing its content after each 3 seconds.this list view i am using for showing the visitor list who are visiting the site.Each row of list contains ipaddress,statustext,duration time,noofvisit and button text and data is updating and changing in list this part is working fine.

Actually i have an issue i have to the row on the top as first row of listview if status text is chat request.How can i do this?can anyone help me?

Actually i am using tabhost after login screen tabhost contains for tab one for monitoring window that show list of visitor and other are chat window,operatorlist and controls.

As i define above if i got status chat request then that row should appear on the top and will contains two button Accept and deny and on accept button click a window will open for chat and deny will use for refusing chat.

Can anyone help me for solving this issue?

my code is following

```
public  class BaseActivity extends Activity  {

private ListView list =null;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1010;
public static Timer timer = new Timer();
private  String response;
protected Dialog m_ProgressDialog;
String[] operatorList,operatorDetail,operatordetail,tempoperatordata;
String[] noofvisitors,opt;
private static final String DEB_TAG = "Error Message";
public static ArrayList<String> SessionText,IPText,DurationText,StatusText;
private ArrayList<String> NoOfVisit,ButtonText;
private int sizeoflist;
private String IP;
Context context;
private CustomAdapter adapter;
public static String from,sessionid,id,text,iptext,status,temo;
private int position,noofchat;
private boolean IsSoundEnable,IsChatOnly;
private Button logout;

NotificationManager notificationManager;



final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
private String url;

private Handler handler; 





public void TimerMethod()
{
    //This method is called directly by the timer
    //and runs in the same thread as the timer.

    //We call the method that will work with the UI
    //through the runOnUiThread method.
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);

} 

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        //This method runs in the same thread as the UI.               
        try{

            getVisitorDetailFromServer();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            Log.i("UPDATE", "Handler called");

            list.invalidateViews();
            playSound3();


        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("UPDATE ERROR", "error");
        }


    }


};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.visitor);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list01);

    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogout);

    //list.addView("chat request", 0);





    //-----------------Making the object of arrayList----------------

    SessionText = new ArrayList<String>();
    IPText = new ArrayList<String>();
    DurationText = new ArrayList<String>();
    StatusText = new ArrayList<String>();
    NoOfVisit = new ArrayList<String>();
    ButtonText = new ArrayList<String>();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        IsSoundEnable = Controls.IsSoundEnable;
        IsChatOnly = Controls.IsChatOnly;
        IsSoundEnable = extras.getBoolean("IsSoundOnly", Controls.IsSoundEnable);
        IsChatOnly= extras.getBoolean("IsCOnlyhat", Controls.IsChatOnly);
        extras.getString("From");
        position=extras.getInt("Position");


    }



}



@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();


    //------------Getting the visitor detail-------------------------

    try{
        getVisitorDetailFromServer();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 7000); 




    //---------------When user click on logout button-----------------------------------


    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try{
                logoutFromServer();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }


    });


}

private void playSound3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.newvisitors);

    mp.start();

}




//----------------------------Getting the detail from server of monitoring window-------------------------


private void getVisitorDetailFromServer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    url = "http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_AllOnline;
    postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("nvar","Y");
    postParameters.put("conly", "N");


    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {

                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);
                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );

                //System.out.println("Output of httpResponse:"+response);

                String result = response;
                result = response;

                String delimiter1 = "<ln>";
                String delimiter2 = "<blk>";

                String[] temp = result.split(delimiter2);
                operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);
                if(temp.length==7){
                    String visitorString = temp[0];
                    String strSound = temp[3];
                    String strCSRmsgOrChatTrans = temp[4];
                    String stroperator = temp[5];
                    String strvisitor = temp[1];

                    visitorString =  visitorString.trim();
                    if(!(visitorString.equals(""))||(visitorString.equalsIgnoreCase("No Visitors online")||(visitorString.equalsIgnoreCase("No Users Online")))){
                        operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);
                        //sizeoflist =operatorDetail.length;
                    }
                    else{

                        sizeoflist = 0;
                    }

                }

                else{

                    sizeoflist = operatorDetail.length;
                }

                //System.out.println("operatordetail length"+operatorDetail.length);


                System.out.println("firstresponse================"+operatorDetail[0]);
                if(operatorDetail[0].equalsIgnoreCase("logout")){
                    sizeoflist = 0;
                    System.exit(0);
                    finish();
                }

                if(temp[0].equalsIgnoreCase("No Users Online")){
                   if(temp[1].equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                       sizeoflist =0;
                }
                   else if(temp[1].length()>0){
                       sizeoflist = 0;
                   }
                   else if(temp[0].equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        sizeoflist = 0;
                    }
                    sizeoflist =0;
                }
                else{
                    sizeoflist =operatorDetail.length;
                }





                //operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);

                //--------Getting the size of the list---------------------

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){



                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //playsound3();
                        noofchat =0;

                        list.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(BaseActivity.this));

                        list.getDrawingCache(false);
                        list.invalidateViews();
                        list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        list.requestFocus(0);
                        list.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
                        //list.setSelected(true);


                        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }


                        });


                    }


                });
            }

            else {

                //ShowAlert();
            }


        }
    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();




}


//--------------------When internet connection is failed show alert

private void ShowAlert() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setTitle("Live2Support");
    alert.setMessage("Internet Connection failed");
    alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //startActivity(new Intent(CreateAccount.this,CreateAccount.class));
            alert.dismiss();

        }
    });

    alert.show();
}


//------------------------Getting the notification of no.of visitor on the site---------------------------

private void triggerNotification() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CharSequence title = "No Of visitors";
    CharSequence message = "New visit";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, noofvisitors[0], System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;


    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, L2STest.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(BaseActivity.this, title, noofvisitors[0], pendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    playsound4();

}

public void completed()    {
    //remove the notification from the status bar
    mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}


private void playsound4() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.newvisitsound);

    mp.start();

}



//-----------------Logout from server--------------------

private void logoutFromServer() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String url ="http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_LOGOUT;

    final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try{
        postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());
        postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);

                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );

                System.out.println("Output of httpResponse:"+response);







            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //  notificationManager.cancelAll();]


                        System.out.println(response);
                        showAlert1();

                        //getSharedPreferences(Main.PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().commit();
                        Log.e(DEB_TAG, response);
                        //System.exit(0);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this,Main.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        //closeHandler();

                    }


                });
            }


        }


    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();


}



//----------------------Logout alert when user click on logout button------------------


private void showAlert1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "You have Successfully logout.";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 200, 200);
    toast.show();
}



//-------------------Play sound3 when any new user visit----------------


private void playsound3() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.newvisitors);

    mp.start();

}


//------------------The adapter class------------------------------


private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;




    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {

        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();

        SessionText.clear(); 
        IPText.clear(); 
        DurationText.clear(); 
        StatusText.clear(); 
        NoOfVisit.clear(); 
        ButtonText.clear(); 



    }


    public int getCount() {
        return sizeoflist;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row1, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.IP = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ip);
            holder.duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
            holder.status =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            holder.noOfVisit = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NoOfvisit);
            holder.invite =(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnjoin);
            holder.deny = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btndeny);
            //holder.accept = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnaccept);


            holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            holder.invite.setId(position);
            holder.invite.setTag(position);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }


        String result = response;

        String delimiter = "<fld>";
        String delimiter1 = "<ln>";



        for(int i=0;i<operatorDetail.length;i++){
            if(operatorDetail!=null){

                //System.out.println("Operator res=============="+operatorDetail[i]);


                operatorList = operatorDetail[i].split(delimiter);

                try{

                    if(operatorList[0]!=null){
                        SessionText.add(operatorList[0]);
                        sessionid = operatorList[0];
                    }
                    else{
                        onStart();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(operatorList[1]!=null){
                        IPText.add(operatorList[1]);
                        iptext = operatorList[1];
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Oplst is null");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(operatorList[4]!=null){
                        DurationText.add(operatorList[4]);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Oplst is null");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(operatorList[3]!=null){
                        StatusText.add(operatorList[3]);
                        status = operatorList[3];
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Oplst is null");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(operatorList[2]!=null){
                        NoOfVisit.add(operatorList[2]);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Oplst is null");
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //ButtonText.add(operatorList[6]);




                try{
                    if(IPText!=null){

                        holder.IP.setText(IPText.get(position));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(DurationText!=null){

                        holder.duration.setText(DurationText.get(position));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try{
                    if(StatusText!=null){

                        holder.status.setText(StatusText.get(position));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try{
                    if(NoOfVisit!=null){
                        holder.noOfVisit.setText(NoOfVisit.get(position));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }




                //----------------If status is chat request then check for this-----------------

                try{
                    if(StatusText.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("chat request")){
                        //playsound();
                        playsound();
                        holder.deny.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.invite.setText("Accept");
                        holder.deny.setText("Deny");
                        convertView.bringToFront();
                        convertView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                        convertView.setSelected(true);
                        //convertView.setFocusable(true);
                        convertView.requestFocus();
                        convertView.clearFocus();


                        holder.invite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                holder.invite.setText("Join");
                                holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                                try{
                                    chatRequest(IPText.get(position), SessionText.get(position));
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this,Chat1.class);
                                i.putExtra("ID", id);
                                i.putExtra("Position",position);
                                i.putExtra("From", from);
                                try{
                                    i.putExtra("SessionText",SessionText.get(position));
                                    i.putExtra("IPTEXT",IPText.get(position));
                                    i.putExtra("StatusText",StatusText.get(position));
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else{
                        holder.invite.setText("Invite");
                        holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        //---------------------When user click on invite Button---------------------


                        holder.invite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                timer.purge();

                                try{
                                    if(SessionText!=null){
                                        callToServer(SessionText.get(position));
                                    }

                                    else{

                                        System.out.println("null");

                                    }
                                }
                                catch(Exception e){

                                    e.printStackTrace();


                                }

                            }
                        });


                    }

                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }







                //-----------------------------When user click on deny button------------------------

                holder.deny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        timer.purge();
                        try{
                            if(SessionText.get(position)!=null){
                                refuseToServer(SessionText.get(position));
                                holder.deny.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            }
                            else{
                                System.out.println("null");
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }




                });


                //-----------When user click on the listiview row-----------------------

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        timer.purge();

                        if(SessionText!=null&&IPText!=null){
                            try{
                                Intent i=new Intent(BaseActivity.this,VisitorDetail.class);
                                i.putExtra("ID", id);
                                i.putExtra("Position",position);
                                i.putExtra("From", from);
                                i.putExtra("SessionText", sessionid);
                                i.putExtra("IPTEXT",iptext);
                                startActivity(i);

                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        else{

                            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                                public void run() {
                                    TimerMethod();
                                }

                            }, 0, 5000); 
                        }



                    }});


            }

        }

        operatorDetail=null; 
        operatorList=null; 


        operatorDetail = result.split(delimiter1);



        return convertView;
    }


    class ViewHolder {
        TextView IP;
        TextView duration;
        Button deny;
        TextView status;
        TextView noOfVisit;
        Button invite;
        Button accept;
    }
}


//------------------Play sound when user click on invite button-------------------------

private void playSound2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.invite);

    mp.start();

}


//---------------When any chat request come-----------------

private void playsound() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chatinvitation);

    mp.start();

}



//------------When user click on deny button---------------------


private void refuseToServer(String sessionid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //final String url = "http://sa.live2support.com/cpn/wz-action.php?";
    url = "http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_ACTION;

    final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    postParameters.put("action","refuse");
    postParameters.put("csesid", sessionid);


    postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());


    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);
                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );


                System.out.println("Deny Chat response:"+response);


                System.out.println("Deny chat Success"+IP); 


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        System.out.println("response================="+IP);

                        showAlert(IP);

                    }



                });
            }


        }


    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();

}



//---------------------When user click on invite button-----------------------


private void callToServer(String session) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    url = "http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_ACTION;

    final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

    postParameters.put("action","cinvt");
    postParameters.put("csesid", session);

    postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());


    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);
                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );


                System.out.println("Output of httpResponse:"+response);

                IP = response;
                System.out.println("the resultant ip ===================="+IP);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        playSound2();

                        System.out.println("response================="+IP);

                        showAlert(IP);

                    }



                });
            }


        }


    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();

}

//------------------Show invitation alert----------------------

private void showAlert(String ip) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Invitation sent to "+ip;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 50, 50);
    toast.show();
}


//-----------------When in response we get the chat request--------------------------

private void chatRequest(String iptext, String sessionid) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    url = "http://"+Main.tempurl+"/"+Main.url1+"/"+Url.IDS_ONCHATREQUEST;

    final HashMap<String, String> postParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();


    postParameters.put("csesid", sessionid);
    postParameters.put("ipaddr", iptext);

    postParameters.put("sid",Main.siteId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("adminid",Main.loginId.getText().toString());
    postParameters.put("join", "Y");


    Runnable searchThread = new Runnable(){

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost1(url,postParameters);

                Log.i(DEB_TAG, "Requesting to server"+response);
                //CustomHttpClient.getResponseInString(response );


                System.out.println("Output of httpResponse:"+response);

                IP = response;
                System.out.println("the resultant ip ===================="+IP);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(response!=null){

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        playSound2();

                        System.out.println("response================="+response);

                        showAlert(IP);

                    }

                });
            }

        }


    };

    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, searchThread, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();

}



public void onNotifiyDataSetChanged(){
    super.notifyAll();
}




@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(BaseActivity.this,Main.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);          
        return true;    
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



}
```

what can i do for setting the row that has chat request on the top?Can anyone help me?

Comment: Give the code, and explain it. Show the problem precisely.

Comment: Do you have a seperate class with these values?ipaddress,statustext,duration time,noofvisit and button text

Comment: no for these values i am using arraylist...........

Comment: If list contains 50 item and any row has contains chat request then it is creating problem to user and also when status change to chat request then sound also appear until user not accept the chat clicking on accept button.........

Answer (score 0):

Create you customListItem with visibility set to `View.GONE` by default. When you have a chat request, then just change its visibility to `View.VISIBLE` and refresh your list. Simple.

Comment: Means? Can you please clearly explain what you actually need to do in your question only?

Comment: yes,you can see in my code i am checking for if(StatusText.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("chat request")) if any status text has text chat request then i want it will be first item of list.............\

Comment: Then can't you get the contents of that chat request and refresh the listview with first row with those contents and rest as you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add some view as the first row of your listview, then use

```
listview.addHeaderView(myHeaderView);
```

use this before setting list adapter.

Comment: I can use it for static data if i am adding in my list.but my listview contains dynamic data........

Comment: you can create dynamic view showing dynamic values. You can also inflate different view and set dynamic data to the view and use the same as list header

Answer (score 0):

try like this..

```
   boolean bool=true;
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {

          while(bool){

              int t=StatusText.IndexOf(chat)
                              if(t!=-1)
                              {
                               Collections.swap(StatusText,0,t);
                                Collections.swap(SessionText,0,t);
                              Collections.swap(IPText,0,t);
                            Collections.swap(DurationText,0,t);
                         Collections.swap( NoOfVisit ,0,t);
                         Collections.swap(ButtonText,0,t);
                                }
                           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {

                         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                    }
                });
```

Comment: if i am using this then chat request case button is not appearing because if i have the status chat request then i am showing two button except and deny otherwise invite.i am using if the code u provide me button is not showing and also it is not appearing on top......

Comment: StatusText.IndexOf(chat)<--- this line is correct... right? are you searching for the word "chat" in StatusText array list? or any other word?

Comment: i am checking as if(StatusText.getPosition().equals("chat request") because Statustext is an arraylist............

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9081/discussion-between-user1008203-and-raju)